# Elasticsearch Global timeout setting not reflected in search response's took parameter

Tags: search, elasticsearch, timeout, elasticsearch-5

We have setup a global timeout for an elasticsearch (5.3.3) cluster in elasticsearch.yml -

search.default_search_timeout: 1nanos

But the responses we get for this, in most cases, have "timed_out": true. However, sometimes, we do get the expected response from elasticsearch with "timed_out": false. However, when "timed_out" is false, we do see that the "took" is returning values > 30 which means the time taken by elasticsearch was around 30ms which is > 1 nanosecond. Ideally the query should have timed out at 1 nanosecond. Is thsis a bug?

Comment: You really think 1nano could work ^^ ?

Comment: This was done to test if the setting actually works.